# How to Set the Global MSVC Toolset Version in Visual Studio 2022 (Not Per Project)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, unreal-engine5

I'm encountering an issue with Visual Studio 2022 ver 17.7.4 and Unreal Engine 5.3. It seems that Unreal Engine is detecting my MSVC toolset version as 14.29, but I have MSVC toolset version 14.37.32822 installed globally on my system. This is causing compatibility problems between Unreal Engine and Visual Studio.

Is there a way to set the global MSVC toolset version in Visual Studio 2022 so that it's recognized by Unreal Engine 5.3 without having to configure it on a per-project basis? I have installed the UE5 through EpicGames as I don't to build it from the source.

I've checked the project settings in Unreal Engine, and while I can specify the toolset version for individual projects, I'd like to establish a global setting that applies to all projects, if possible. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.